# How can I compare array value and print it if matches?

Tags: arrays, jsp, for-loop

This is my jsp page. Here I'm comparing two array values and printing it if both match:

```
<body>
    <%
        String[] basic = {"IND"};
        String[] result = {"USA", "UK", "IND", "PAK"};
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (basic[i] == result[i]) {
                out.println(basic[i]);
            }
        }
    %>
</body>
```

I end up getting an array out of bound exception. In the basic array `IND` has to compare with each string in result array. If there is a match, it needs to print, the value. How can I do this?

Comment: If you follow the MVC paradigm, add business logic in view isn't the best way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your `basic` variable has only one value which goes out of bounds since you increment `i` based of `result.length`. You might need to use 2 loops, depending on what you have to do.

```
String[] basic = {"IND"};
String[] result = {"USA", "UK", "IND", "PAK"};
for (int i = 0; i < basic.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
        if (basic[i].equals(result[j])) {
            out.println(basic[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i know that,how can i get my requirement by changing the code

Answer (score 3):

```
<%
    String[] basic = {"IND"};
    String[] result = {"USA", "UK", "IND", "PAK"};
   for (int j = 0; i < basic.length; i++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (basic[j].equalsIgnoreCase(result[i])) {
            out.println(basic[j]);
        }
    }
%>
```

better use equalsIgnoreCase rather than equals.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <body>
    <%
        String[] basic = {"IND"};
        String[] result = {"USA", "UK", "IND", "PAK"};
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (basic[0].equals(result[i])) {
                out.println(basic[i]);
            }
        }
    %>
</body>
```

There is only one element in your basic array so use basic[0].

Also You need to use `.equals` instead of `==`

Or else use 2 loops

```
 <%
        String[] basic = {"IND"};
        String[] result = {"USA", "UK", "IND", "PAK"};
       for (int j = 0; i < basic.length; i++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (basic[j].equals(result[i])) {
                out.println(basic[j]);
            }
        }
    %>
```

Comment: if i have String[] basic={"MY","IND","AUS","NZ"} then how can i compare?